# The type or namespace name 'Sclient' could not be found in 3 tier application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, three-tier

While tring to implement a 3 tier application, I copy pasted the files and completed the steps in below link in 10 minutes.

http://geekswithblogs.net/edison/archive/2009/04/05/a-simple-3-tier-layers-application-in-asp.net.aspx

However I recieve an error "The type or namespace name 'Sclient' could not be found", My client, configuration and genericdata classes are in App_Code folder, and I recieve error in  ClientList.ascx line 6.

My codes are exactly same as indicated in link, what could be the error cause?

Below is the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to add reference to any required DLLs?

Comment: Forgot to add `using SClient;` ?

Comment: @edocetirwi, I didn't add dlls, namespace is defined within the same project, doesn't it should see the Sclient automatically?, and there is no mention of adding dlls in the instructions.

Comment: @Reniuz, no you can see the SClient from the screenshot

Comment: @Henk Holterman, yes, but I have double checked, please see the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click to project and choose "Convert to Web Application"